# Put details in 'Unable to Submit for Approval' response

Tags: approval-process

When a user clicks on Submit for Approval button and for some reason the record can not be put in Approval Process we have this error message

> Unable to Submit for Approval
>   This record does not meet the entry criteria or initial submitters of any active approval processes. Please contact your administrator for assistance.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Can I put some kind of description in such a response? From time to time users ask me why they can't submit a record for an approval. I want to put some description in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current solution.  In the past, I've custom-coded the submit screen to guide the user through missing fields before.  This was a custom button pointing at a visualforce page and an an apex controller method that would be executed on-load of the page to submit the approval process and redirect the user.

You might want to take that approach so you can tailor the use cases to your users.  Many orgs have 10+ approval processes on Quote, and so if you submit as a user, you it's hard for the system to assume which you should be entering.

Comment: I don't really want to create separate pages just to put this description... But that is my understanding too, that there is no standard way to provide a user with at least any error message.